# What's the safest way to play Fallout 3 (GOTY edition for PS3) to avoid corrupt quests?

Tags: ps3, fallout-3

I've just purchased a new copy of Fallout 3 (yay!). But, I'm a little worried about the bugs that may plague the game. Bethesda seems to struggle here and there with their console ports. Does anyone have any tips for my future travels in the fallout universe?

Comment: It sounds like you're borrowing trouble before it happens.  From what I can tell, there are glitches, but none that will outright kill your game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a safest way to play other than saving regularly. Also if you are being really cautious you might want to take a look around here though be careful of spoilers:

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_bugs

n.b. If you find something called a MIRV be cautious when using it!